# Get date week different between Spark SQL date_format and weekofyear

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

A very simple:

```
SELECT  date_format("2018-01-14", "w"), weekofyear("2018-01-14")
```

Gives:

```
3, 2
```

They should both return 2, how can I configure the locale correcly?

(Environment `user.country` = fr `user.lang` = FR)

I can see [in Spark weekofyear code source](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/bd08a9e7af4137bddca638e627ad2ae531bce20f/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/datetimeExpressions.scala#L477) that the week start at Monday.

Answer (score 2):

As of version 2.2.1 (but also on the current `master` branch), `date_format` is defined in [`DateFormatClass`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.2.1/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/datetimeExpressions.scala#L451-L487), which in turn uses [`DateTimeUtils#newDateFormat`,](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.2.1/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/util/DateTimeUtils.scala#L112-L120) which unfortunately uses an hard-coded `Locale.US`, leaving you no option to configure its behavior.

```
def newDateFormat(formatString: String, timeZone: TimeZone): DateFormat = {
  val sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(formatString, Locale.US)
  sdf.setTimeZone(timeZone)
  // Enable strict parsing, if the input date/format is invalid, it will throw an exception.
  // e.g. to parse invalid date '2016-13-12', or '2016-01-12' with  invalid format 'yyyy-aa-dd',
  // an exception will be throwed.
  sdf.setLenient(false)
  sdf
}
```

So it seems like those two are bound to have different behaviors. Perhaps you may want to [have a look at their bug repository](https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/SPARK/issues/SPARK-23000?filter=allopenissues) and possibly file a ticket for this.